# XBox 360 no longer displaying video - However, no RROD

Tags: xbox-360

So I went to turn on the 360 yesterday to play some NCAA as I like to do from time to time and noticed that nothing came up on the screen.

I found this odd and then looked to see if there was any red-ring of death notification; however, there wasn't.  So I'm not quite sure if there is a repair I can do myself.

Leading up to this the video was starting to act goofy....almost like the videocard wasn't able to render everything and keep up.  It was like layers were missing from the video and the quality had gone to crap.  I assume this is a video card issue....

Any ideas on how to fix this?

I'm guessing I'm SOL but am hoping someone can help me out.

Comment: Tried replacing the video cables? Could be faulty / old wiring, or even the ports on your TV / Monitor / Projector.

Comment: Yes, I also made sure to check the connections and re-seat them.  Everything looks fine from that point of view

Comment: Test the Xbox on a different TV with a different cord and see if you still get no video.

Comment: Nothing?  Not even "E47" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undoubtedly a video card issue. I had something similar, only it was displaying just green gobbledygook. Your only recourse is to call up Microsoft and hope it's under warranty -- or replace it.

Sorry.

Comment: You're right - that's what it was and it's no longer under warranty.  Not happy....stupid videocard

Comment: @PSU: Sorry, bud. :(

Comment: I have the same issue - but I also have a second Xbox 360 with a working video card *(but [broken CD drive](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39433/how-do-i-replace-an-xbox-360-dvd-drive-if-the-original-drive-is-broken), which is apparently even less repairable than the video card...)*. So @John, would you happen to know **how** to go about "replacing the video card?"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft You can't replace the "video card" -- it's a GPU that's soldered to the motherboard. Also, you can't replace the CD drive, because it's keyed to the motherboard. However, you can replace the CD drive optics, if you keep the controller board with the motherboard. There are a few connections you have to unsolder. Put the controller board from the non-working drive into the working drive and it will then work with the working machine's motherboard.